# Login with Google Plus after I can't logout

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin

I'm trying to Sign in my application with Google Plus. First time when I try, It ask me permission and I accept it. After I go to my Google Plus profile and delete my application. Now I try to re-sign in but it doesn't ask me any permission. If I add to new scope in GoogleApiClient configuration it ask me again..

How can I clear my phone permanently my application?

I try like this;

```
if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            Log.d("deneme", "Google Profile shutdown");
        }
        else
            Log.d("deneme", "Google already shutdown");
```

And another problem, I'm try to get user' s profile information like this, I got error.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Log.d("deneme", "onConnected");
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(currentPerson.isPlusUser())
            Log.d("deneme", currentPerson.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```

[image]

```
public class NotRegistered extends SherlockFragment implements View.OnClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.d("deneme","onStart");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d("deneme","onStop");
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("deneme", "onActivityCreated");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    vf.setFlipInterval(11000);
    vf.startFlipping();

    Button b_gmail = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BTN_sign_gmail);
    Button m_loginButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BTN_register);
    Button m_registerButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BTN_login);

    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    mSignInButton = (SignInButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    b_facebook = (LoginButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BTN_sign_facebook);
    b_facebook.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    b_facebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "email", "user_status", "user_about_me"));
    b_facebook.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_facebook_button);
    b_facebook.setFragment(this);

    m_loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    m_registerButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    b_gmail.setOnClickListener(this);   
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("deneme", "Not Register onCreateView");
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notregistered_fragment, container, false);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
        .addApi(Plus.API, null)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
    return view;
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState sessionState, Exception exception){
    if(sessionState.isOpened()){
        Log.d("deneme", "Oturum Açık");
        Log.d("deneme", session.getAccessToken());
        //boolean returnVal = new UserRecord().execute(val);
        makeMeRequest(session);
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Pager.class);
            startActivity(i);
            getActivity().finish();
    } else {
        Log.d("deneme", "Oturum Kapalı");
    }
}

private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                if (user != null) {
                    new NewUserAsync().execute("facebook", user.getUsername(), user.getFirstName(), 
                            user.getLastName(), user.getProperty("email").toString(), user.getId(),
                            user.getBirthday().toString());
                }
            }
            if (response.getError() != null) {
                Log.d("deneme",response.getError().toString());
            }
        }
    });
    request.executeAsync();

}


private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, "callback");
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Register register = new Register();
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.BTN_sign_gmail:
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                Log.d("deneme", "Google profili sonlandırılamadı");
            else
                Log.d("deneme", "Google profili sonlandırıldı");
        } else
            Log.d("deneme", "Oturum zaten kapalı");
        break;
    case R.id.BTN_register:
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.test, register, "register").commit();
        break;
    case R.id.BTN_login:
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Pager.class);
        startActivity(i);
        //getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.test, register, "register").commit();
        break;
    case R.id.sign_in_button:
        if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()){
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "küçük buttona tıklandı", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("deneme", "onActivityResult");

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        if(resultCode != getActivity().RESULT_OK){
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }
    }

    mIntentInProgress = false;
    if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()){
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
    Log.d("deneme", "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    Log.d("deneme", "onPause");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    Log.d("deneme", "onResume");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d("deneme", "onSaveInstanceState");
}

public static final String TAG = "deneme";
private LoginButton b_facebook;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

// Google Plus Connect Starting

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Kullanıcı bağlı", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("deneme", "onConnected");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if(!mIntentInProgress){
        mConnectionResult = result;
        if(mSignInClicked){
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}

private void resolveSignInError() {
    Log.d("deneme", "Buraya bir geldi : resolveSignInError");
      if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
          mIntentInProgress = true;
          mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), RC_SIGN_IN);
          Log.d("deneme", "resolveSignInError try içerisinde");
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
          mIntentInProgress = false;
          mGoogleApiClient.connect();
          Log.d("deneme", "resolveSignInError catch içerisinde");
        }
      }
    }

SignInButton mSignInButton;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
boolean mIntentInProgress = false;
boolean mSignInClicked;
int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
}
```

Line 241 : public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) function.

Firstly, How can I remove my test users and how can I get their profile information..

Thank you for help..

Comment: Sorry I can't add my log: http://213.243.53.12/log.png

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is good for both questions (check information and log out user), your problem is a NullPointerException.
Check your class NotRegistered line 241.

My bet is that your mGoogleApiClient is not initialized.
Could you show me where do you initialize the mGoogleApiClient?

Comment: Thanks for attention. Actually I don't think my problem about GoogleApiClient initialize because when I add new scope it ask me permission. I added all of my code.

Comment: Put a mGoogleApiClient!=null validation on line 241 and try again. It seems that in your "onconnectionsuspended" the client is null

Comment: Another point, if you are starting the app and you get the onconnectionsuspended" event... is that something is going wrong. Have you requested your api key and registered in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is late but i think you should add inside on create

```
// Initializing google plus api client
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```